# Android Studio jdwp: processIncoming log

Tags: android, debugging, logging, android-studio

Good day, I am having some trouble with the log report of Android Studio when developing on an Asus Memopad 7.
The log keeps getting filled up with the following 2 lines repeated endlessly:

```
D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x40002E59, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
```

I don't know the meaning of it and it does not happen when developing the same application on different devices. It is not an error (the app seems to work) but it becomes really really difficoult to debug.
Does anyone know what this is and why it's repeated in a loop?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The Answer has been given here, i think it's enough
[jdwp_processIncomin at stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34044053/log-messages-processincoming-handlepacket-sendbufferedrequest-is-repeated-a-lo)