# log messages processIncoming, handlePacket, sendBufferedRequest is repeated a LOT - android

Tags: android, logcat

my app was in the background and i was checking the log i saw that the app sending log messages intensively with messages that i could not understand.

I use GCM push notification and i have doubt that it can be the reason.

If it is the reason! Battery will not like sending this much requests in less than a second.

This is the logcat messages:

```
12-02 15:01:07.682 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: processIncoming
12-02 15:01:07.682 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x4000027D, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
12-02 15:01:07.682 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
12-02 15:01:07.798 2548-2548/com.mbh.gsmtest D/OpenGLRenderer: Flushing caches (mode 0)
12-02 15:01:08.183 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: processIncoming
12-02 15:01:08.183 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x4000027E, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
12-02 15:01:08.183 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
12-02 15:01:08.683 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: processIncoming
12-02 15:01:08.683 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x4000027F, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
12-02 15:01:08.683 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
12-02 15:01:09.185 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: processIncoming
12-02 15:01:09.185 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x40000280, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
12-02 15:01:09.185 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
12-02 15:01:09.686 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: processIncoming
12-02 15:01:09.686 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x40000281, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
12-02 15:01:09.687 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
12-02 15:01:10.186 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: processIncoming
12-02 15:01:10.186 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x40000282, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
12-02 15:01:10.187 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
12-02 15:01:10.689 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: processIncoming
12-02 15:01:10.689 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x40000283, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
12-02 15:01:10.690 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
12-02 15:01:11.009 2548-2548/com.mbh.gsmtest D/VelocityTracker: VelocityTracker: int datax = 10
12-02 15:01:11.010 2548-2548/com.mbh.gsmtest D/VelocityTracker: VelocityTracker: int m_velocity_magnify_x = 1.000000
12-02 15:01:11.010 2548-2548/com.mbh.gsmtest D/VelocityTracker: VelocityTracker: int datay = 10
12-02 15:01:11.011 2548-2548/com.mbh.gsmtest D/VelocityTracker: VelocityTracker: int m_velocity_magnify_y = 1.000000
12-02 15:01:11.191 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: processIncoming
12-02 15:01:11.191 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x40000284, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
12-02 15:01:11.193 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
12-02 15:01:11.425 2548-2548/com.mbh.gsmtest I/SurfaceTextureClient: [STC::queueBuffer] (this:0x5f4e4270) fps:5.63, dur:4086.97, max:3632.61, min:12.16
12-02 15:01:11.691 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: processIncoming
12-02 15:01:11.691 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x40000285, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
12-02 15:01:11.692 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
12-02 15:01:11.722 2548-2548/com.mbh.gsmtest I/AbsListView: Fling from scroll with initialVelocity = 0,mActivePointerId = 0,mFirstPosition = 1,firstChildTop = -172,this = android.widget.ListView{428b9bc8 VFED.VC. .F....ID 0,0-720,1006 #7f0f00c9 app:id/listView_configs}
12-02 15:01:12.194 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: processIncoming
12-02 15:01:12.194 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x40000286, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
12-02 15:01:12.194 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
12-02 15:01:12.441 2548-2548/com.mbh.gsmtest I/SurfaceTextureClient: [STC::queueBuffer] (this:0x5f4e4270) fps:56.15, dur:1015.08, max:74.91, min:5.35
12-02 15:01:12.695 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: processIncoming
12-02 15:01:12.695 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x40000287, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
12-02 15:01:12.695 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
12-02 15:01:13.197 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: processIncoming
12-02 15:01:13.197 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x40000288, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
12-02 15:01:13.197 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
12-02 15:01:13.698 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: processIncoming
12-02 15:01:13.698 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x40000289, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
12-02 15:01:13.699 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
12-02 15:01:14.200 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: processIncoming
12-02 15:01:14.200 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x4000028A, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
12-02 15:01:14.200 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
12-02 15:01:14.321 2548-2548/com.mbh.gsmtest I/SurfaceTextureClient: [STC::queueBuffer] (this:0x5f4e4270) fps:7.44, dur:1880.83, max:1679.93, min:13.46
12-02 15:01:14.701 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: processIncoming
12-02 15:01:14.702 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x4000028B, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
12-02 15:01:14.702 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
12-02 15:01:15.202 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: processIncoming
12-02 15:01:15.202 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x4000028C, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
12-02 15:01:15.202 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
12-02 15:01:15.331 2548-2548/com.mbh.gsmtest I/SurfaceTextureClient: [STC::queueBuffer] (this:0x5f4e4270) fps:34.70, dur:1008.57, max:470.44, min:7.54
12-02 15:01:15.702 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: processIncoming
12-02 15:01:15.702 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x4000028D, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
12-02 15:01:15.702 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
12-02 15:01:16.204 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: processIncoming
12-02 15:01:16.204 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x4000028E, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
12-02 15:01:16.205 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
12-02 15:01:16.661 2548-2548/com.mbh.gsmtest I/SurfaceTextureClient: [STC::queueBuffer] (this:0x5f4e4270) fps:42.81, dur:1331.53, max:427.37, min:5.29
12-02 15:01:16.704 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: processIncoming
12-02 15:01:16.704 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x4000028F, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
12-02 15:01:16.704 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
12-02 15:01:17.205 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: processIncoming
12-02 15:01:17.205 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x40000290, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
12-02 15:01:17.205 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
12-02 15:01:17.705 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: processIncoming
12-02 15:01:17.705 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x40000291, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
12-02 15:01:17.705 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
12-02 15:01:18.209 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: processIncoming
12-02 15:01:18.209 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x40000292, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
12-02 15:01:18.210 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
12-02 15:01:18.216 2548-2548/com.mbh.gsmtest I/SurfaceTextureClient: [STC::queueBuffer] (this:0x5f4e4270) fps:1.29, dur:1555.18, max:998.46, min:556.72
12-02 15:01:18.708 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: processIncoming
12-02 15:01:18.708 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x40000293, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
12-02 15:01:18.708 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
12-02 15:01:19.210 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: processIncoming
12-02 15:01:19.210 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x40000294, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
12-02 15:01:19.210 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
12-02 15:01:19.222 2548-2548/com.mbh.gsmtest I/SurfaceTextureClient: [STC::queueBuffer] (this:0x5f4e4270) fps:63.63, dur:1005.83, max:35.90, min:5.19
12-02 15:01:19.710 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: processIncoming
12-02 15:01:19.710 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x40000295, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
12-02 15:01:19.711 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
12-02 15:01:20.211 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: processIncoming
12-02 15:01:20.211 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x40000296, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
12-02 15:01:20.212 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
12-02 15:01:20.235 2548-2548/com.mbh.gsmtest I/SurfaceTextureClient: [STC::queueBuffer] (this:0x5f4e4270) fps:54.28, dur:1013.23, max:169.05, min:5.19
12-02 15:01:21.242 2548-2548/com.mbh.gsmtest I/SurfaceTextureClient: [STC::queueBuffer] (this:0x5f4e4270) fps:62.61, dur:1006.23, max:37.54, min:4.56
12-02 15:01:21.715 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: processIncoming
12-02 15:01:21.716 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x40000299, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
12-02 15:01:21.716 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
12-02 15:01:22.216 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: processIncoming
12-02 15:01:22.217 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x4000029A, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
12-02 15:01:22.217 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
12-02 15:01:22.244 2548-2548/com.mbh.gsmtest I/SurfaceTextureClient: [STC::queueBuffer] (this:0x5f4e4270) fps:61.88, dur:1001.99, max:33.40, min:5.36
12-02 15:01:22.717 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: processIncoming
12-02 15:01:22.717 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x4000029B, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
12-02 15:01:22.717 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
12-02 15:01:23.219 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: processIncoming
12-02 15:01:23.219 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x4000029C, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
12-02 15:01:23.219 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
12-02 15:01:23.248 2548-2548/com.mbh.gsmtest I/SurfaceTextureClient: [STC::queueBuffer] (this:0x5f4e4270) fps:62.74, dur:1004.19, max:39.09, min:6.05
12-02 15:01:23.719 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: processIncoming
12-02 15:01:23.719 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x4000029D, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
12-02 15:01:23.720 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
12-02 15:01:24.220 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: processIncoming
12-02 15:01:24.221 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x4000029E, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
12-02 15:01:24.221 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
12-02 15:01:24.251 2548-2548/com.mbh.gsmtest I/SurfaceTextureClient: [STC::queueBuffer] (this:0x5f4e4270) fps:49.85, dur:1002.94, max:221.33, min:7.34
12-02 15:01:24.722 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: processIncoming
12-02 15:01:24.722 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x4000029F, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
12-02 15:01:24.722 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
12-02 15:01:25.223 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: processIncoming
12-02 15:01:25.223 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x400002A0, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
12-02 15:01:25.224 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
12-02 15:01:25.253 2548-2548/com.mbh.gsmtest I/SurfaceTextureClient: [STC::queueBuffer] (this:0x5f4e4270) fps:62.89, dur:1001.70, max:33.27, min:5.31
12-02 15:01:25.725 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: processIncoming
12-02 15:01:25.725 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x400002A1, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
12-02 15:01:25.725 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
12-02 15:01:26.226 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: processIncoming
12-02 15:01:26.226 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x400002A2, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
12-02 15:01:26.227 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
12-02 15:01:26.257 2548-2548/com.mbh.gsmtest I/SurfaceTextureClient: [STC::queueBuffer] (this:0x5f4e4270) fps:60.72, dur:1004.64, max:46.58, min:10.01
12-02 15:01:26.727 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: processIncoming
12-02 15:01:26.727 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x400002A3, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
12-02 15:01:26.727 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
12-02 15:01:27.228 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: processIncoming
12-02 15:01:27.228 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x400002A4, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
12-02 15:01:27.228 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
12-02 15:01:27.263 2548-2548/com.mbh.gsmtest I/SurfaceTextureClient: [STC::queueBuffer] (this:0x5f4e4270) fps:46.75, dur:1005.40, max:286.60, min:6.88
12-02 15:01:27.730 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: processIncoming
12-02 15:01:27.730 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x400002A5, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
12-02 15:01:27.731 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
12-02 15:01:28.232 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: processIncoming
12-02 15:01:28.234 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x400002A6, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
12-02 15:01:28.234 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
12-02 15:01:28.270 2548-2548/com.mbh.gsmtest I/SurfaceTextureClient: [STC::queueBuffer] (this:0x5f4e4270) fps:60.54, dur:1007.56, max:44.81, min:8.74
12-02 15:01:28.734 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: processIncoming
12-02 15:01:28.734 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x400002A7, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
12-02 15:01:28.734 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
12-02 15:01:29.233 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: processIncoming
12-02 15:01:29.233 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x400002A8, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
12-02 15:01:29.233 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
12-02 15:01:29.278 2548-2548/com.mbh.gsmtest I/SurfaceTextureClient: [STC::queueBuffer] (this:0x5f4e4270) fps:62.54, dur:1007.39, max:31.36, min:5.80
12-02 15:01:29.734 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: processIncoming
12-02 15:01:29.734 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x400002A9, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
12-02 15:01:29.735 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
12-02 15:01:30.235 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: processIncoming
12-02 15:01:30.235 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x400002AA, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
12-02 15:01:30.235 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
12-02 15:01:30.439 2548-2548/com.mbh.gsmtest I/SurfaceTextureClient: [STC::queueBuffer] (this:0x5f4e4270) fps:21.53, dur:1161.21, max:787.65, min:6.23
12-02 15:01:30.736 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: processIncoming
12-02 15:01:30.736 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x400002AB, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
12-02 15:01:30.737 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
12-02 15:01:31.238 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: processIncoming
12-02 15:01:31.238 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x400002AC, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
12-02 15:01:31.238 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
12-02 15:01:31.453 2548-2548/com.mbh.gsmtest I/SurfaceTextureClient: [STC::queueBuffer] (this:0x5f4e4270) fps:43.38, dur:1014.25, max:311.59, min:4.95
12-02 15:01:31.739 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: processIncoming
12-02 15:01:31.740 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x400002AD, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
12-02 15:01:31.740 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
12-02 15:01:32.240 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: processIncoming
12-02 15:01:32.240 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x400002AE, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
12-02 15:01:32.240 2548-2554/com.mbh.gsmtest D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
12-02 15:01:32.488 2548-2548/com.mbh.gsmtest I/SurfaceTextureClient: [STC::queueBuffer] (this:0x5f4e4270) fps:45.41, dur:1035.03, max:292.95, min:7.63
```

Any body has faced this kind of message ?

Comment: frustated a lot with these logs, coming in thousands, can't even see my logs

Comment: @ShirishHerwade you are right me too, the solution is to use log filters, set specific tags for your log messages and filter the logcat to show the specific tag that you have already set, good luck

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As you suspected, all the log messages have nothing to do with `GCM`, it is the debugger the one who generates all this messages, to be more precise, the `JDWP debugger`:

> The Dalvik VM (Virtual Machine) supports the JDWP protocol to allow debuggers to attach to a VM. Each application runs in a VM and exposes a unique port that you can attach a debugger to via DDMS. If you want to debug multiple applications, attaching to each port might become tedious, so DDMS provides a port forwarding feature that can forward a specific VM's debugging port to port 8700. You can switch freely from application to application by highlighting it in the Devices tab of DDMS. DDMS forwards the appropriate port to port 8700. Most modern Java IDEs include a JDWP debugger, or you can use a command line debugger such as jdb.

You don't have to worry about all this messages affecting you battery, the messages will be generated only if your device will have the `USB debugging` option enabled, but with almost no cost for you battery (see [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/16250/what-is-usb-debugging-can-i-keep-it-on-forever) thread for more details)

`Disable ADB Integration` by unchecking in `Tools -> Android -> Enable ADB Integration`. Keep in mind that this will get rid of JDWP messages, but also **will prevent you from doing CPU, GPU, Memory, Network monitoring**.

Other option is to fold the messages from the logcat (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33585818/1787796) answer). The disadvantage is that all folded lines will stack on the same line, no line feed being added.

Also you have the possibility to filter messages based on their tags and log level (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19931987/how-to-filter-logcat-in-android-studio) thread)

Hope it helps.

Comment: A similar thing is happening in my log-cat; however, it only happens when I run the app on Andorid 4.1 device. 
If I run the app on newer versions, I wouldn't see any extra logs. Do you have any idea what the reason is for this behavior?